# Getting attributes from child class in many_to_many fields

Tags: python, django, models

there is sample code:

models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    any attr_A
    ....

class B(A):
    any attr_B
    ....


class C(models.Model):
    a = models.ManyToManyField(A)
```

views:

```
c = C()
b = B()
c.a.add(b) - add B class instance
c.save()

...

a = c.a.all()
a[0].attr_B
```

But "a" list contains A class instances and I can't get attributes for class B.

How I can get class B attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no relation between A and B, its just inheritance. It should be:

```
class A(models.Model):
    any attr_A
    ....

class B(A):
    any attr_B
    ....


class C(models.Model):
     a = models.ManyToManyField(B)
```

Even if it would be a relationship, it should be that way:

```
class A(models.Model):
    any attr_A
    ....

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    any attr_B
    ....


class C(models.Model):
     a = models.ManyToManyField(A)
```

and then:

```
a[0].b.attr_B
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance), to access the instance of the sub class in multi-table inheritance, use `a[0].b` which is a `B()` instance and has `attr_B`s on it, if `a[0]` is an instance of the model `A`.
Thus `a[0].b.attr_B` works here.